# List Item scrolling vertically like news sticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a news sticks. There are lot of jquery plugin available I tried using them. But I found no one suite for me.

This is my HTML -

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="feeds" id="feeds">
        <li class="category-main">main category 01</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 01</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 02</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 03</li>
        <li class="category-item">Sub category 04</li>                        
        <li class="category-main">main category 02</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 01</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 02</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 03</li>
        <li class="category-sub">Sub category 04</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here I want to display 3 list item at once (one main category and 2 sub categories) when items auto scrolling vertically.

Recently I tried with Jquery [Advance News Ticker](http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/index.html) plugin. It was close but not 100%

This is an [example](http://www.icc-cricket.com/) for what I exactly looking for. (Check it under main navigation bar there). Only difference is I need to display main category like red color background button there alone with 2 subcategories.

Can I get any solution from professionals here to how can I do with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple vertical ticker for you. It's far from perfect, but you should be able to build off this to how you want it. http://jsfiddle.net/uyw6j/1/

css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 64px;
    background: gold;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#feeds {
    position: relative; /* must have position relative or absolute for it to animate */
}
```

jquery :

```
function ticker() {
    $('#feeds').animate({
        top: '-220px' //this animates the ul upwards, or you could just do 220 to animate it downwards
    }, 6000, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '0' // this resets the animation to the begining position
        }, 0);
        ticker(); // this loops the ticker animation so it restarts from the beginning and keeps going
    });
}

ticker();
```

Comment: user000000, Thanks for your answer. But this is not the way what I am expecting. This is an [example](http://www.icc-cricket.com/) what I exactly looking for...

Comment: you can check [this link](http://i57.tinypic.com/jaewdg.jpg) which I have attached an image there for better understanding.